# Favorable, avantageuse, disposé?

Tags: expressions, choix-de-mot, expressions-idiomatiques, formulation-idiomatique, reformulation

> C’est la partie de Trivia Crack en cours qui m’est la plus favorable.

> C’est la partie de Trivia Crack en cours qui m’est la plus avantageuse.

> C’est la partie de Trivia Crack en cours qui m’est la mieux disposée.

D’autres variantes à proposer?

Merci

Comment: Comment est-ce qu'un jeu comme ça peut vous être favorable?

Comment: Par exemple, si le pointage d’une partie est de 0-5 et d’une autre 1-2, on s’entend que la deuxième partie m’est plus favorable que la première , non?

Comment: Elle est m’est plus favorable au sens d’elle est plus à mon avantage.

Comment: Non, à mon avis, je ne pense pas que l'on dirait qu'un numéro de points gagnable  dans une partie du jeu "est favorable à soi ou pas". On les gagne ou pas.

Comment: Il s’agit de pointages non définitifs car les parties en question sont toujours en cours, c’est le premier joueur qui atteint six points qui remporte la partie.

Comment: En mettant en parallèle toutes les parties auxquelles je prends part, on peut certainement dire que l’une d’elles m’est plus favorable que les autres, sans pour autant que j’aie l’avantage numérique.

Comment: avoir des ou x points en [sa, votre, etc.] faveur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Qui m’est la plus bénéfique.
> Qui m’est la plus profitable.

Answer (score 1):

> [Par exemple, si le pointage d’une partie est de 0-5 et d’une autre
> 1-2, on s’entend que la deuxième partie m’est plus favorable que la
> première , non?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/49949/favorable-avantageuse-dispos%C3%A9#comment103045_49949)

Ton propos implique que tu es la personne qui a respectivement 0 et 1 points dans ces parties. Je dirais simplement que la deuxième partie est plus (celle où le pointage est le plus) *serrée* et que c'est la *meilleure* des deux [*jusqu'à présent*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=1447) (parmi tes parties en cours).

Comment: Déductivement on comprend qu’un joueur a x points et un autre y points dans (0-5 ou 1-2), d’autant plus que l’information voulant que le jeu se joue à deux (sinon à plusieurs) est précisée plus bas dans les commentaires.

Comment: Je suis entièrement d’accord avec toi.